# Barcode Scanner with zxing In windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, zxing, barcode-scanner

how can i decode the QrCode Or barcode With zxing library . 
for test project i generate QrCode my self . now i want decode this with same library and fill the result in text block .
let me i explain with my code

```
public WriteableBitmap GenerateQRCode(string phoneNumber)
{
    var _writer = new BarcodeWriter();
    _writer.Renderer = new WriteableBitmapRenderer()
    {
        Foreground = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255)

    };
    _writer.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
    _writer.Options.Height = 244;
    _writer.Options.Width = 446;
    _writer.Options.Margin = 1;
    _writer.Options.PureBarcode = true;
    var barc = _writer.Write("tel:" + phoneNumber);
    ImageGenrate.Source = barc;
    var ss = Decode(barc);

    return barc;
}

public void Decode( WriteableBitmap sImage)
{
    var br = new BarcodeReader();
    br.Decode(sImage);
}
```

in GenerateQRCode Method i generate QrCode and in Decode method I decode QrCode.
how Can i see the Decode Result ?

Comment: Which port of ZXing are you using? Google does not maintain it's own.

Comment: what you mean by port ?

Comment: ZXing is a Java library maintained by Google. To use it in .NET, someone have to convert it to e.g. C#, as Google does not do this themselves. Where did you get the library? Which NuGet package or webpage?

Comment: I get with Visual studio NuGet Package . and zxing version is zxing wp8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume you are using [ZXing.Net](http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/) ([NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net/)).

`BarcodeReader.Decode(WritableBitmap)` returns an object of type `Result`. This object has properties `string Text` and `byte[] RawBytes`.

```
public string Decode(WriteableBitmap sImage)
{
    var br = new BarcodeReader();
    var result = br.Decode(sImage);
    if (result != null)
    {
        return result.Text;
    }
    return null;
}
```